# URL Redirect causing loop

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, http-redirect

Below is my .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^axiom/?$ /axiom/publish.htm [L]
```

This is causing a redirect loop. If I comment out

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

The page will load.I'm not sure where my error is but I'm assuming it's in here somewhere.

Comment: What is purpose of `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]` rule?

Comment: To redirect http requests to https.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This rule is redirecting you to the same url you are accessing -

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Consider you are accessing http://www.example.com/test/a.html. This rewrite rule matches test/a.html and

```
REQUIEST_URI = test/a.html
HTTP_HOST = www.exmpale.com
```

So you are redirecting to https://www.example.com/test/a.html

then you are matching the same condition and being redirected to the same page again !

if you are trying to redirect from http to https then you need to add another condition to check if it is from http or https

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [L]
RewriteRule ^axiom/?$ /axiom/publish.htm [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} ^off$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: That did it and now I completely understand what was happening. Thanks for the direction!